# How to execute external windows software command line in php exec()?

Tags: php, exec

I download a copy software name fastcopy, and it gives a command line to execute copy files.
The command :

> A basic format is as follows.
>
> fastcopy.exe [/options] file1 file2
>   ... [/to=dest_dir]
>
> Please use space character(' ') as
>   separator(not semicolon). If filename
>   contains space character, please
>   enclose with dobule quotation marks.
>   Ex) fastopy.exe C:\Windows "C:\Program
>   Files" /to="D:\Backup Folder\"
>
> Supported options are as follows.
>   (Please don't put space characters
>   before and behind "=")
>
> /cmd=(noexist_only|diff|update|sync|force_copy|move|delete)
>   ... Specify operation mode. (By
>   default, diff mode is used. If delete
>   mode is specified, then "/to=" option
>   isn't used.)

So, my original code to execute the fastcopy.exe was:

```
// fastcopy the software folder
$cmd = 'D:\\fastcopy\\fastcopy.exe d:\\files.rar /to="e:\\"';
exec( $cmd,$result)
```

but it seem didn't work.

So, How to execute it??

[fastcopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) web page

link to direct [download](http://ipmsg.org/archive/FastCopy206.zip) only 300kb

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you're using double-backslashes when you shouldn't be. Single quotes strings don't need your backslashes escaping unless it's the very last character in the string.

Comment: A Guess is not an answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: @Robert Without replicating his exactly scenario, any answer will be a guess. It's most likely the correct answer however, and he can't mark a comment as the answer. So I disagree - it shouldn't be a comment. Maybe I should remove the "just a guess" from my post, but I don't really think it matters that much though.

Comment: You could of commented asking him/her to add more information about the issue, SO is not totally about getting your answers accepted and earning reputation but being correct and providing the best answer for all who may see the answer. Its not a large issue just a mere notice for the future, and you cannot be sure that you are correct as exec performs the command via cmd, and I have just testing the commands and they executed as expected.

Comment: Just to clarify - my choice of it being an answer vs a comment had nothing to do with SO reputation. I thought it was the answer, so I put it as an answer. As you say, it's not a large issue - I just wanted to mention this, as your comment suggests that my choice was about reputation, which is incorrect. This is the last I'm going to comment on this petty issue.