# Different between windows cmd and PHP exec() to execute command?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, exec

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735471/how-to-execute-external-windows-software-command-line-in-php-exec).I had asked how to execute an external program [ fastcopy ] command line.But I found that the same command will work different in **windows cmd mode** and **php exec()**.

When I am running in **windows cmd mode**.The target program window was launched and did the job as it would.

**E.g:**

I am going to copy several files to **different removable disk** and the program [ **fastcopy** ] could determine that if the same destination it will wait until the prev file was finished copy.In another words.If the files which will copy to the  same destination would copied one by one , at the same time it copies other files to other destinations.

But **in PHP exec() command.** The **PHP** will do the job behind for you,the program [ **fastcopy window** ] does't launch and lose the ability to copy to different destination at the same time.

So, I just need some advices to make it clear why these happen? Or something I did wrong!!

Comment: @Dagon please post this as an answer so I can upvote it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any output from an app launched by exec() is sent to php, so you dont see it, unless you want to, see the manual page for exec for how to see the output.